# Port Forwarding works only localy

Tags: linux, rest, ubuntu, tomcat, portforwarding

I have Tomcat server (on Ubuntu) running on port 8080 and I want to connect externally, but Port-Forwarding works only in LAN. port fw :
HTTP Server 0.0.0.0 80  192.168.1.246   8080    TCP

and when put req. on my router WAN IP it wont respond (timeout).
I m not even sure where the problem could be..
netstat:
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*        LISTEN      7767/java

Answer (score 1):

You have to point *:80 to 192.168.1.246:8080 and it will be fine. Right now you try authorize the IP 0.0.0.0 on the port 80 to access your IP 192.168.1.246 on the port 8080 which is not correct.

Comment: Ok then use *:80 instead *:8080. It will do what you asking for

Comment: HTTP Server (empty) 80 192.168.1.246 8080 TCP, is not working